# ADO functionality.. copy, filter, paste from closed workbook to active wrokbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently looking for an alternative to the solution below, but using the ADO functionality so that the source workbook isn't opened. I am imagining this will decrease processing time?

Your thoughts..

Thanks

```
Sub CopyFilteredValuesToActiveWorkbook()

    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("\\Linkstation\rrm\X_DO_NOT_TOUCH_CC\MasterLogFile\Masterlogfile.xlsx", , True) 'Readonly = True
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("LogData")
    wsSource.Range("$A$1:$H$3").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Opera"
    Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("A:Z")

    Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("MLF")
    Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("A:Z")

    rngDest.Value = rngSource.Value 'Copies values over only, if you need formatting etc we'll need to use something else

    wbSource.Close (False) 'Close without saving changes

    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't add tag in the title. See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing this line:

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

For some reason Win XP will not run without it. It should be placed right after `con.Open conStr`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a reference to Active X Data Objects 6.0, to use SQL queries

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Public Sub GetValues (path as String, destination as Range)
    Dim conStr as String, strSQL as string
    Dim con as new ADODB.Connection, rs as new ADODB.Recordset

    conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & path & "';" & _
             "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [LogData$] WHERE [CriteriaColumn] = 'Opera'"

    con.Open conStr
    rs.open strSQL, con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    destination.CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.close
    con.close
End Sub
```

Where the CriteriaColumn is the Header of the Column used as criteria to filter

You can call the subroutine as follows:

```
Dim path as string, rngDest as Range
path = "\\Linkstation\rrm\X_DO_NOT_TOUCH_CC\MasterLogFile\Masterlogfile.xlsx"
'The Upper left cell of the range that will receive the data:
Set rngDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MLF").Range("A1") 
GetValues path, rngDest
```

Comment: This looks like a pretty advanced technique.. so "CriteriaColumn" is replaced by the actual header name in the source sheet.  I'm a bit confused where to input the other details

Comment: Yes. If the Cell in the first line of that Column contains "Navigator", you should replace CriteriaColumn by Navigator.
This may seem a bit complicated, but is a very flexible way to get data and works with relational Databases or Text files with minor changes. see [This Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819) for more datails or [This Link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) for a SQL Primer

Comment: I will indeed study the links you have kindly provided for full clarity. Still a bit confused as to where the source workbook location is?

Comment: The path of the source workbook is passed by a parameter, as well as the range that will receive the data. I'll edit the answer for clarity

Comment: this looks to be the parameter for the source but what about the target?

Comment: The destination is the same of the code in your question, or just the upper left cell in the range (as shown in my edit). If You have headers in the destination worksheet, just set the rngDest to A2 cell

Comment: +1 and worth mentioning that ADO 2.8 is functionally equivalent to ADO 6.0 but 2.8 has the advantage of being available on Windows XP whereas 6.0 is available on Vista or later

Comment: As @barrowc said it is very important to know the version of The OS.
[This](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) is an very useful site that enumerates the connection strings to another types of files or databases. It's worth bookmarking

Comment: yes that site is useful and I can see the reference you have used.. it looks to be correct, I am using vista, and Excel 2007. I have placed the code in ThisWorkbook at present and nothing is happening :(

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69651453/TEST1.xlsm       I'm not sure how to properly "set" this?